# How to avoid hardcoding in column selection in data frame in apache spark | Scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-ml

I have the following data frame and I need to run logistic regression using spark ml on it:

```
uid  a  b  c  label d
1    0  1  3  0     2
2    3  0  0  1     0
```

While using the the ml package, i came to know that I need to create the data in the format

```
label  feature
0      [0,1,3,2]
1      [3,0,0,0]
```

Now i came across VectorAssembler to create the feature column and while doing so I need to do something like

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols(Array("a", "b", "c", "d"))
.setOutputCol("features")
```

Is there anyway i can avoid the hardcoding of individual feature column names

Comment: `df.columns.diff(Seq("uid", "label"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your data. If you know that you will always have a certain set of columns that is not a part for your feature vector (uid and label) AND can assume that all other columns are, you can do like this:

```
// df is your data frame
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
.setInputCols(df.columns.diff(Array("uid","label")))
.setOutputCol("features")
```